# differentiating struct based on type

Tags: c, struct

I have two different structures with a type field define(Please see below).

```
struct A {
int type;
char type_a[8];
char random[8];
};


struct B {
int type;
char type_b[16];
char random[16];
};
```

Now I want to differentiate this two structures based on type So for example

```
if (type == A)
struct A *a = (struct A *)buff;
if (type == B)
struct B *b = (struct B *)buff;
```

I don't know what type of structure is passed to me in buff before hand. So how do I extract type from the buff. The type field is guranteed to be the first field in both the structures.

Comment: you mean buff will be a void*

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is your intented use?

Comment: Here is a project to help  http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Comment: What you want is known in C circles as a "smart union"

Answer (score 3):

You can do this type of thing with an OOP design pattern in C.

The idea here is that a `Base` structure has a `type` member. Structures `A` and `B` "extend" `Base`. Since the `Base` structure is the first member of both `A` and `B`, either can be cast to `Base` and used as such.

That'll give you a safe way to cast in between `Base` and `A` or `B` while giving compile-time type safety when you just need to use an instance of `Base`.

```
typedef struct Base {
    int type;
} Base;

typedef struct A {
    Base base;
} A;

typedef struct B {
    Base base;
} B;

int ATYPE = 1;
int BTYPE = 2;

int getType(Base *base) {
    return base->type;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    B *bptr;
    Base *base;
    int baseType;

    a.base.type = ATYPE;
    b.base.type = BTYPE;

    base = (Base*)&b;

    baseType = getType(base);

    // something like this is reasonable,
    // since you know that base is an
    // instance of B.
    if (baseType == BTYPE) {
        bptr = (B*)base;
    }

    if (baseType != BTYPE) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is true because the Standard guarantees that there be no padding before the first member of a struct.

Comment: @H2CO3 that it the only think that socket address struct works other wise every thing become platform dependent. You given **very Important point**.

Answer (score 1):

C has the [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29) feature for data structures such as this.  A union is similar in appearance to a struct but each member in the union occupies the same memory location.  You then use another field, `type` in the example below, so that you can know how to interpret the struct.

Using this you can approach your problem without any casting at all and retain compile-time type safety.

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TYPE_A 1
#define TYPE_B 2

struct A
{
    char member1[8];
    char member2[8];
};

struct B
{
    char member1[16];
    char member2[16];
};

struct base
{
    int type;
    union
    {
        struct A a;
        struct B b;
    } data;
};

char *get_member2(struct base *buff)
{
    if (buff->type == TYPE_A)
        return buff->data.a.member2;

    if (buff->type == TYPE_B)
        return buff->data.b.member2;

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct base b1;
    struct base b2;

    /* Set up test structs. */

    b1.type = TYPE_A;
    strcpy(b1.data.a.member2, "Hello");

    b2.type = TYPE_B;
    strcpy(b2.data.b.member2, "World");

    /* Print member2 from each struct. */

    printf("%s\n", get_member2(&b1));
    printf("%s\n", get_member2(&b2));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
```

[code: Codepad](http://codepad.org/JCOSqNIM)

Comment: Don Good answer! you should write an example to demonstrate user. your answer is best

Comment: OK - I've amended my answer to include a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want/cannot change A and B:

```
#define TYPE_A 0
#define TYPE_B 1
```

...

```
struct *B create_B()
{  struct *B= malloc(sizeof B);
   B->type=TYPE_B;
   return B;
}
```

...

```
void *buff=create_B();
```

...

```
struct A a;
a.type=TYPE_A;
void *buff=&a;
```

...

```
struct A *a=NULL;
struct B *b=NULL;
int type = *((int *)buff);
if (type == TYPE_A)
 a = (struct A *)buff;
else if (type == TYPE_B)
   b = (struct B *)buff;
```

The problem with your code is that scope of a and b is only inside the if, and probably you need it more.

Comment: that's not the point here. The question is can the pointer buff can be recognized as struct A* or struct B* if it is passed as void*

Comment: @me.deeiip I assumed the type is already know, as the first you read from a file for example.